# Why does the content overflow the column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I am trying out bootstrap columns, so I have a column which occupies 8 parts of the row, And the second part occupies the 4 parts. But the 8 parts div has more content, and it is overflowing. how to stop that behaviour.

```css
.bggreen {
  background: green;
}
.bgred {
  background: red;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 bggreen border">This is not normal column. This is supposed to be a bigger column which occupies 8 parts of the row, while the next div occupies only 4 parts ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bgred border">This is ver small</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hum i see a problem brake the dots on parts to see if it is making it on second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the default behaviour since the dots do not have a breaking character and is treated as a single word. You can use `word-wrap: break-word` for creating a new line after the *parts* text or `word-break: break-all` to continue the dots with the text.

```css
.bggreen {
  background: green;
}
.bgred {
  background: red;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-md-8.bggreen.border {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 bggreen border">This is not normal column. This is supposed to be a bigger column which occupies 8 parts of the row, while the next div occupies only 4 parts ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bgred border">This is ver small</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.bggreen {
  background: green;
}
.bgred {
  background: red;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-md-8.bggreen.border {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 bggreen border">This is not normal column. This is supposed to be a bigger column which occupies 8 parts of the row, while the next div occupies only 4 parts ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bgred border">This is ver small</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the difference between overflow: hidden and word-wrap: break-word

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on the parent element will not show the text beyond the width of it. But `word-wrap: break-word` will break the extra characters will make sure the height is expanded and fits the width.

Answer (score 2):

Word-wrap property breaks the text and avoids the overflow. In your css file add the following style.

```
.col-md-8.bggreen.border
{
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

you can visit this website http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/WebDevelopment/CSS/FailSafeCSS1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Define a class `hideOverflow` with overflow hidden and then text-overflow property to ellipsis. That will do the trick.

```css
.hideOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
}
.bggreen {
  background: green;
}
.bgred {
  background: red;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-md-8.bggreen.border {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 bggreen border hideOverflow">This is not normal column. This is supposed to be a bigger column which occupies 8 parts of the row, while the next div occupies only 4 parts ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bgred border">This is ver small</div>
  </div>
</div>
```